# Correct approach for using flux and component lifecycle

Tags: reactjs, flux

I'm migrating the code from what I see on here on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OwdbBJ).

Within `IssueBox`, I am planning to implement a form which an enduser will update setting a state from 'unverified' to 'verified'.

`App` (ill rename this component) will be my parent and `IssueBox` would be the child.

So I got through flux => Action -> dispatcher -> udpate db -> update view.

Now that I have the new state and the view should be updated, do I use componentWillRecieveProps() and then setState there, so that in `IssueBox` I can continue using this.props thus in turn updating it.

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
  import IssueBox from "./issuebox.js";
  import "./App.css";

  class App extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
        isLoaded: false,
        email: [],
        counter: 0,
        title: "Test run"
      };
    }

    componentDidMount() {

      fetch(
        "https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/311743/dummy-emails.json"
      )
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(result => {
          const emails = result.data;
          console.log("resutl state: ", emails);
          let id = 0;
          for (const email of emails) {
            email.id = id++;
            email.verified = 'False'
          }
          this.setState({
            isLoaded: true,
            emails: emails
          });
        });
    }
    render() {
      //console.log(this.state.email);
      return (
        <div className="App">
          <div>
            <IssueBox emails={this.state.email} />
          </div>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }


  //issuebox.js

  import React, { Component } from "react";

  class IssueBox extends Component {
    constructor(args) {
      super(args);

      const emails = this.props.emails;
      console.log("inner props: ", emails);
      let id = 0;
      for (const email of emails) {
        email.id = id++;
      }

      this.state = {
        selectedEmailId: 0,
        currentSection: "inbox",
        emails
      };
    }
```

//...copy and pase from codepen

```js
setSidebarSection(section) {
  let selectedEmailId = this.state.selectedEmailId;
  if (section !== this.state.currentSection) {
    selectedEmailId = "";
  }

  this.setState({
    currentSection: section,
    selectedEmailId
  });
}

componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
  // Assign unique IDs to the emails

  this.setState({ emails: newProps.data });
}

render() {
  const currentEmail = this.state.emails.find(
    x => x.id === this.state.selectedEmailId
  );
  return (
    <div>
      <Sidebar
        emails={this.props.emails}
        setSidebarSection={section => {
          this.setSidebarSection(section);
        }}
      />
    )}

  ///.....copy and pase from codepen
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is being caused by this line in `componentWillReceiveProps()`:

`this.setState({ emails: newProps.data });`

The emails are coming in on a property called `emails` so that line should be:

`this.setState({ emails: newProps.emails });`

That being said, `componentWillReceiveProps()` [gets called more frequently than you might expect](https://developmentarc.gitbooks.io/react-indepth/content/life_cycle/update/component_will_receive_props.html#props-may-not-change).  I recommend that you add the `id`'s to the emails within `componentDidMount()` of `App` so they come into `IssueBox` ready to use.  This means that `App` is keeping the emails in its state and simply passing them to `IssueBox` as props, so you can remove `emails` from the state in `IssueBox` and just use the emails that come in through the props everywhere within `IssueBox` (similar to how the other components use `emails` coming in on their props and don't keep them in their own local state).

Comment: Hey Brian, thanks for the advice, I did as you said and it worked. So, now I have a follow up questions, which lifecycle hook I should use. ShouldComponentUpdate or can I use forceUpdate? These items within `SideView` will have their state updated from "unverified" to verified.

Comment: The approach taken in the codepen is a good one.  All of the data lives in the state of App and gets passed to stateless child components as props.  If the child components need to do something to the data (like change from "unverified" to "verified") then App passes them callbacks in their props that they can call to alter the state in App.  Then they simply render what they are given in props.  Whenever the state changes in App they get updated props and re-render automatically.  Initial loading of state data in App can be done in componentDidMount like you are doing.